# Javascript not working in HTML when running node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom

When I try to run `node app.js` I get no errors but none of the HTML elements work as intended. I am requiring script.js in app.js.

This is the code I am using to try and fix the issue.

This code is in srcipt.js:

```
require('jsdom-global')();
const fs = require('fs');
let htmlString = fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString();
document.documentElement.innerHTML = htmlString;
global.document = window.document;

let btn = global.document.getElementById("clicker");
let ageInput: any = global.document.getElementById("age");
let foodInput: any = global.document.getElementById("food");
```

Comment: When running your app under Node, you don't have access to `document` or DOM. If you want to operate on the HTML elements server-side, you need to parse the document first.

Comment: node.js = server side, browser = client side. In node.js there is no `window` object.